# How can a pandas groupby .sum return wrong values?

Tags: python, pandas

When applying a `groupby` to a DataFrame the resultant grouped values do not sum to the same figures as when taking the column sums of the original DataFrame. How is this possible? I can't show my full data as it's sensitive and, more annoyingly, I can't seem to recreate the problem. The example below talks it through though.

Say I have this dataframe, `df2`:

```
    A      B    C   D
0   One    1    3   2
1   Two    NaN  6   4
2   Three  3    NaN 8
3   One    4    17  NaN
4   Two    7    NaN 2
5   Three  12   8   15
```

Summing it returns this as expected:

```
`df2.sum()`
    A    OneTwoThreeOneTwoThree
    B                        27
    C                        34
    D                        31
    dtype: object
```

Then using this `groupby`:

`df3 = df2.groupby(['A'])[['B', 'C', 'D']].sum()`

Returns this:

```
        B   C   D
A           
One     5   20  2
Three   15  8   23
Two     7   6   6
```

And summing that returns the same values as summing the original columns:

```
df3.sum()
B    27
C    34
D    31
dtype: float64
```

In my actual data, however, the original values are:

```
13496 non-null float64
11421 non-null float64
10890 non-null float64
10714 non-null float64
```

Yet after the same `groupby` as above using `.sum()`, the grouped rows sum to:

`13021`
`11071`
`10568`
`10408`

Is there some pandas caveat or gotcha I'm missing here? How are values being lost? This is obviously less of a direct programming question that can be answered, and more of a pandas 'internal workings' question. I don't see anything in the pandas documentation about this, nor are there any SO questions about it.

Comment: what do you get from `df3 = df2.groupby(['A'])[['B', 'C', 'D']]`?

Comment: Weird. Maybe some rounding down is going on. You should check if you can replicate the strange behavior with a dataframe of roughly the same size where the values are randomly generated float64s

Comment: @ppaulojr - If I apply that method to my df I get the same wrong values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any `NaN` values in column A?  This can produce the behavior that you're describing, because `NaN` values get dropped when they're being grouped.  Consider the DataFrame below:

```
     A    B     C      D
0    x  1.0   NaN  100.0
1    x  2.0  21.0  105.0
2    y  NaN  22.0  110.0
3  NaN  4.0  23.0  115.0
4    z  5.0  24.0  120.0
5    z  6.0  25.0    NaN
```

Then `df.sum()` produces:

```
B     18.0
C    115.0
D    550.0
dtype: float64
```

But `df.groupby('A')['B', 'C', 'D'].sum().sum()` produces:

```
B     14.0
C     92.0
D    435.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think you can add test for NaN values in column `A`,  maybe something like`df.A.isnull().sum()`

Comment: That's it - both answers hit the nail on the head, @ptrj was just quicker.

Comment: My answer was first, actually.

Comment: My mistake. Amended.

Answer (score 2):

It can be explained if `A` has nan values.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,3)))
>>> df['A'] = np.random.randint(0,2,5)
>>> df['A'][0] = np.NAN
>>> df
Out[52]: 
   0  1  2   A
0  2  1  5 NaN
1  6  9  7   0
2  5  2  6   1
3  8  4  7   0
4  2  3  4   1
>>> df.sum()
Out[53]: 
0    23
1    19
2    29
A     2
dtype: float64
>>> np.sum(df.groupby(by = 'A').sum())
Out[54]: 
0    21
1    18
2    24
dtype: int64
```