# I’m getting different sums while doing groupby and sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe, and I was trying to use the groupby function on multiple columns while performing the sum on multiple other columns.

To verify my results, I took one column from the original dataframe and computed the sum. Then, I applied the groupby function to the dataframe and aggregated the data, after which I took the sum of the corresponding column. However, I noticed that both sums are not matching.

In theory it should be same but I have a very large dataset so don't know what's happening. Just wanna know can the sum be different and if yes could you guys give me an example so that I can understand?

EDIT:

My original dataframe original_df

result_df= original_df.groupby([column1,column2])[column3,column4,column5].sum()

result_df[column5].sum()

I tried to verify this by using

original_df[column5].sum()

but both sums are not matching

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, it's otherwise only unfounded speculation. Also provide the exact commands that you used.

Comment: I can't upload the data here.                                                                                         I used df.groupby(["column1","column2"])["column3","column4"].sum()

Comment: No you need to [edit] your question. And provide the commands for each step that you described.

Comment: I did please check

Comment: Maybe because you have NaNs in columns [column1, column2]? Then the groupby can provide different results. See the conversation here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480705/how-can-a-pandas-groupby-sum-return-wrong-values)

Comment: Yes, NaNs are most likely the issue. Use `original_df.groupby(['column1', 'column2'], dropna=False)[['column3', 'column4', 'column5']].sum()`

Comment: I get that but how to get the same sum?

Comment: `dropna=False` should do the trick. Please provide an example of data that reproduces your observation.